# How does SASL know to read config from /etc/postfix/sasl?

Tags: postfix, sasl

I've set up Postfix to authenticate with SASL on a Ubuntu based system. I've done this by following along with some recipes, but mostly readying a lot of the docs.

One bit that works, but which I don't understand how it works is based on a recipe from the postfix website. I have created the file `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf`, which I understand is a SASL, not Postfix, configuration file. How does SASL know to check this location for config when working with Postfix? I didn't have to configure SASL to point to this directory, so is it hard coded? Are there any other directories will SASL search in for config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the image below:
[image]

following is the link for the image I have added above.

> https://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html

Please Go to the "**Configuring Cyrus SASL**" Section.
by This postfix read all configuration files under /etc/postfix with suffix of **.conf** .

But to answer your question,

*I didn't have to configure SASL to point to this directory, so is it hard coded*

The answer is "Yes"

if you run the following command in your terminal, you may see that "**smtpd_sasl_path**" is equal to "**smtpd**" as below image:

[image]

The name of the configuration file (default: smtpd.conf) is configurable. It is a concatenation from a value that the Postfix SMTP server sends to the Cyrus SASL library, and the suffix .conf, added by Cyrus SASL.